# Wordpress save wp_editor content using settings API

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

I'm creating a plugin with an admin settings page, and I want to use the settings API.

I am able to save text fields and checkboxes, but when I add a settings field with a `wp_editor` it's not saving..?

I used to do this with `get_option`, but now I want to use a settings class and the `register_setting()` method.

This is my code:

```
public function register_settings() {
    register_setting( 'eman_setting', 'eman_setting', array( $this, 'eman_validate_settings' ) );

    add_settings_field(
        'eman_dashboard_welcome',                      
        __( "", 'emanlang' ),                           
        array( $this, 'eman_dashboard_welcome_callback' ),   
        'management-settings',                          
        'eman_settings_section'         
    );  

}

public function eman_dashboard_welcome_callback() {
    //$content = 'Empty';
    $editor_id = 'textareadashboardwelcome';    
    $args = array('textarea_name' => 'eman_dashboard_welcome');

    if(! empty( $this->eman_setting['eman_dashboard_welcome'] ) ) {
        $content = $this->eman_setting['eman_dashboard_welcome'];
    } else {
        $content = 'The field is empty';
    }

    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $args );

    /** TESTING **/
    echo '<br /><b>testing textarea output: </b>'. $content .'<br /><br />';
    echo '<b>Complete settings array dump: </b><br />';
    echo var_dump($this->eman_setting);

}
```

**Note:** This is only the relevant part of the code. On this page I have multiple 'add_settings_field' which are all working fine.

As you may have noticed, for testing I do a `var_dump()` to check what's inside the options array.

The dump returns:

```
array(3) { ["eman_opt_in"]=> string(2) "on" ["eman_sample_text"]=> string(10) "sample 1.1" ["eman_sample_text2"]=> string(10) "sample 2.2" }
```

After saving the form, the array only contains 3 fields, so the array is not even populated with the [eman_dashboard_welcome]?

I tried many possible solutions, like adding this jQuery:

```
$('#submit').mousedown( function() {
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
});
```

But nothing works... Please help :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it..

Solution:

Textarea / wp_editor 'name' needs to call the field in the array.

In my case:

```
$args = array('textarea_name' => 'eman_setting[eman_dashboard_welcome]');
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $args );
```

Comment: Solid solution. And kudos for taking the time to answer your own question!